# Alternating Random Rows into ListView from SQLite DB - Order Not Correct

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, random

I have two tables in my SQLite db.  I am trying to choose three random rows from table1 and three random rows from table2, and have them alternating in the listView.

(ex)
table1 random row
table2 random row
table1 random row
table2 random row
table1 random row
table2 random row

For some reason it is not alternating the rows from each table in the listView.  It puts them in whatever order it wants.

This is my code to choose the rows and insert them into the chosen table:

```
while (x <= 2) {
                    cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
                    cursor1.moveToFirst();
                    rowId = cursor1.getInt(cursor1.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO chosen SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE _id = '" + rowId + "'");
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE chosen SET _id = '" + newID + "' WHERE _id = '" + rowId + "'");
                    newID++;

                    cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
                    cursor2.moveToFirst();
                    rowId = cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO chosen SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE _id = '" + rowId + "'");
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("UPDATE chosen SET _id = '" + newID + "' WHERE _id = '" + rowId + "'");
                    newID++;

                    x++;
                }
                cursor1.close();
                cursor2.close();
```

This is what I am using to choose the data to populate the listView

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, value FROM chosen ORDER BY _id", null);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be.  Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    while (x <= 2) {
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO chosen (value1, value2, value3) SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1, null);
                    dbHandler.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO chosen (value1, value2, value3) SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM table2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1, null);
                    x++;
                    }
```

Just made sure that the row id column in the chosen table was autoincrement, and kept the listview query the same:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, value FROM chosen ORDER BY _id", null);
```

So much simpler - and works perfectly!